# Programs refuse to run on Ubuntu Lunar Lobster

Tags: drivers

As you can probably tell by the title of this post I have Lunar Lobster installed on my Dell inspiron 15 3000 series laptop.  Libre Office works well with this configuration.  But the eXist database program and SeaTools from Seagate don't.  The splash screen appears but nothing else.  And when I run SeaTools, the splash screen won't stop displaying even if I click the x on the splashscreen.  I'm not sure what is wrong with my system.